# Get filename of derived class from base class in typescript running on node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm looking for a way to get the filename of a derived class from a base class in typescript running on node.js.  An example of this would be:

## Foo.ts

```
export abstract class Foo {
    constructor() { }
    name() { return (__filename); }
    print() { console.log(this.name()); }
}
```

## Bar.ts

```
import { Foo } from './Foo';

export class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor() { super(); }
}
```

## main.ts

```
import { Bar } from './Bar';

let bar = new Bar();
bar.print(); // should yield the location of Bar.ts
```

Due to the number of files involved and just cleanliness I'd like this to be confined to the `Foo` class rather than having an override of the `name()` function in each derived class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **require.cache** to get all cached **NodeModule** objects and filter it to find your module.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requirecache

```
class ClassA {
    public static getFilePath():string{
        const nodeModule = this.getNodeModule();
        return (nodeModule) ? nodeModule.filename : "";
    }
    
    public static getNodeModule(): NodeModule | undefined{
        const nodeModule = Object.values(require.cache)
            .filter((chl) => chl?.children.includes(module))
            .filter((mn)=> mn?.filename.includes(this.name))
            .shift();
        return nodeModule;
    }
}
class ClassB extends ClassA {
    constructor(){}
}

const pathA = ClassA.getFilePath(); //Must return the absolute path of ClassA
const pathB = ClassB.getFilePath(); //Must return the absolute path of ClassB
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort-of solve this with the code:

```
private getDerivedFilePath(): string {
    let errorStack: string[] = new Error().stack.split('\n');
    let ret: string = __filename;
    let baseClass: any = ThreadPoolThreadBase;
    for (let i: number = 3; i < errorStack.length; i++) {
        let filename: string = errorStack[i].slice(
            errorStack[i].lastIndexOf('(') + 1,
            Math.max(errorStack[i].lastIndexOf('.js'), errorStack[i].lastIndexOf('.ts')) + 3
        );
        let other: any = require(filename);
        if (other.__proto__ === baseClass) {
            ret = filename;
            baseClass = other;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (ret || '');
}
```

Added to `Foo`, which will work when called from the constructor to set a private _filename property, for inheritance chains beyond the example above so long as the files are structured with a default export of the class being used.  There may also be a caveat that if a base class from which a derived object is inheriting directly is initialized as a separate instance within the constructor of any member of the inheritance chain it could get confused and jump to another independent derived class - so it's a bit of a hacky work-around and I'd be interested if someone comes up with something better, but wanted to post this in case someone stumbles across this question and it works for them.